# How to display just a part of a responsive svg without keeping the complete svg size

Tags: css, svg

I'm a little bit newbie with all this stuff of svg, etc. Anyway I thing I'm doing well, but I have a little problem. I have an svg logo, responsive. When the screen is big it shows the whole logo, but for phones, etc it only shows the main part of it. The thing is that it displays exactly what i want, but it keeps the size of the complete svg. I'd love to show just one part and play with it, so I can fit everything is I'd love. Did i explain well myself? I hope so, anyway I paste the code and I bring a few screenshots so you can understand better. Thank you.

**My website with part of the logo not displayed:**

[image]

**The whole logo, not stylized:**

[image]

**This is my inline svg code:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="logo" viewBox="0 0 935 502">
    <g id="logo-resto">
        <path d="x" id="logo-jamon-fondo"/>
        <path d="x" id="logo-delicatessen"/>
        <path d="x" id="logo-jamon"/>
    </g>
    <path d="x" id="logo-iberico"/>
</svg>
```

**And here my CSS:**

```
#logo-resto {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but have you played with the viewBox values ?

Comment: The thing is that I want to have just that: http://i.imgur.com/gN300tb.png
If I play with the viewport it changes nothing, right? Because when the website is in a big screen it displays the whole logo: check it here: http://jaimepm.esy.es

Comment: Let me explain better. If i set the width of the svg to 100% of free space, the whole svg will take that space, not just the "Ibérico" word. I'd like to control just that word and make the rest as if doesn't exist in order to set the right size to the logo when the screen is a smartphone one.

Comment: I would break the example out into a jsfiddle for people to play with.

Comment: Done. I hope I did it ok. Try to run it in full screen and resizing the browser.